# operator && cannot be applied to operands type int and int

Tags: c#

Today I started to learn random and I got a problem that I cannot figure out, can someone tell me what did I do wrong?

```
        int  playerNum1, playerNum2;
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int num1 = rnd.Next(1, 11);
        int num2 = rnd.Next(1, 11);
        Console.WriteLine("Insert 2 numbers");
        playerNum1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        playerNum2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        if ((num1=playerNum1) && (num1=playerNum2) && (num2=playerNum2) && (num2 =playerNum1))
```

Comment: Equality comparisons are double `==`.

Answer (score 4):

Comparison in C# is done with == not with =

```
if (num1==playerNum1 && num1==playerNum2 && num2==playerNum2 && num2 == playerNum1)
```

Comment: For clarity, the single equals operator ("=" instead of "==") is the assignment operator, so what you are doing is assigning values and returning the results which cannot be combined into an aggregate condition - hence your error message.